# Sort a data.frame by multiple columns whose names are contained in a single object?

Tags: r

I want to sort a `data.frame` by multiple columns, ideally using base R without any external packages (though if necessary, so be it). Having read [How to sort a dataframe by column(s)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-by-columns-in-r), I know I can accomplish this with the `order()` function as long as I either:

1. Know the explicit names of each of the columns.
2. Have a separate object representing each individual column by which to sort.

But what if I only have one vector containing multiple column names, of length that's unknown in advance?

Say the vector is called `sortnames`.

`data[order(data[, sortnames]), ]` won't work, because `order()` treats that as a single sorting argument.

`data[order(data[, sortnames[1]], data[, sortnames[2]], ...), ]` will work if and only if I specify the exact correct number of sortname values, which I won't know in advance.

Things I've looked at but not been totally happy with:

1. `eval(parse(text=paste("data[with(data, order(", paste(sortnames, collapse=","), ")), ]")))`. Maybe this is fine, but I've seen plenty of hate for using `eval()`, so asking for alternatives seemed worthwhile.
2. I may be able to use the `Deducer` library to do this with `sortData()`, but like I said, I'd rather avoid using external packages.

If I'm being too stubborn about not using external packages, let me know. I'll get over it. All ideas appreciated in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `do.call`:

```
data<-data.frame(a=rnorm(10),b=rnorm(10)) 
data<-data.frame(a=rnorm(10),b=rnorm(10),c=rnorm(10))
sortnames <- c("a", "b")
data[do.call("order", data[sortnames]), ]
```

This trick is useful when you want to pass multiple arguments to a function and these arguments are in convenient named list.

Comment: That's great - I've read over the help file for do.call in the past, and always thought this must be really helpful, but never came up with a good reason to use it. Thanks!

Comment: Note that this will work for data.frame. For matrices you must convert them to lists: `lapply(sortnames,function(x)data[,x])`